# PayPal SOAP TransactionSearch Error (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, soap, paypal

my target is to have a function that give me back all transactions like a bank statement.
To solve these problem, I tried much of functions, talked to the support and many more. The last answer of the support -> "The REST Api doesn't support, use other..."

In this case, I try to use SOAP and the TransactionSearch function. The Code looks well and I found a similar code from an other person, who used this. But I get an error and don't know what's wrong. Maybe anyone can help me?

The Code:

```
Dim client = New PayPalAPIInterfaceClient()
Dim credentials = New CustomSecurityHeaderType()
credentials.Credentials = New UserIdPasswordType
credentials.Credentials.Username = "xxx"
credentials.Credentials.Password = "xxx"
credentials.Credentials.Signature = "xxx"
credentials.Credentials.AppId = "xxx"

Dim request = New TransactionSearchReq()
request.TransactionSearchRequest = New TransactionSearchRequestType
request.TransactionSearchRequest.StartDate = Now.AddDays(-10)
request.TransactionSearchRequest.Status = PaymentTransactionStatusCodeType.Success
request.TransactionSearchRequest.Version = "124.0"

Dim response = client.TransactionSearch(credentials, request)
```

When I run the code, I get a error message like this (sorry, the error message is in german)

> Fehler beim Empfangen der HTTP-Antwort für https://api.paypal.com/2.0/. Die Ursache kann sein, dass die Dienstendpunktbindung kein HTTP-Protokoll verwendet. Eine andere mögliche Ursache ist, dass der HTTP-Anforderungskontext vom Server abgebrochen wird (vermutlich auf das Herunterfahren des Diensts zurückzuführen). Weitere Informationen finden Sie in den Serverprotokollen.

I used the live mode and have Access via a Business Account. But since Friday, our Account runs endless. Could it be, that our problem is a global problem since the ebay/paypal split?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Going off the error, it looks like you are using the wrong endpoint. The error is referencing the API Certificate endpoint but your code shows you are using the API Signature. The API Signature endpoint is https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/